# iPad orientation behaviour inconsistent - changes on each launch?

Tags: ios, ipad, orientation

I have a very strange problem that I am as yet unable to diagnose.

In my iOS app (it's a universal binary), when I run on iPad 4.3, the orientation at launch is inconsistent.

The app delegate adds a splash screen (UIViewController) to the main window, then removes it and adds the app's primary view. It is this primary view which is the issue - approximately half of the time, it loads up correctly in landscape orientation, the other half it loads the view in portrait (though both the status bar and keyboard are correctly in landscape).

I'm at a bit of a loss as to why the orientation at launch is changing, when I am making no changes to the code or the simulator/device orientation.

I have UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft and UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight set as the only supported orientations for iPad in the Info.plist and every view controller is using the following:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        // The device is an iPad running iPhone 3.2 or later.
        if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
            return YES;
        }

    } else {
        // The device is an iPhone or iPod touch.
        if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
            return YES;
        }

    }

    return NO;
}
```

Can anyone help me out with this??

Cheers,

Olly

Comment: Ok, I fixed the problem.

Turns out the iPad didn't like the way I was adding and removing views. I was adding the splash view as the window's rootViewController, then removing it and adding my primary view as the rootViewController.

I solved this by adding a navigation controller (with navigationBarHidden = YES) as the window's rootViewController, then adding my splash screen as the root of the navigation controller. Then I simply push the primary view onto the stack.

Still not sure why the iPad didn't like my original method, but this workaround works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If the status bar and keyboard are always in landscape then the problem should not be in shouldAuto... method. It might be in viewDidLoad. Also, try the following: in project-info.plist, set "Initial interface orientation" as landscape left/right, "clean" the project and run.

Comment: As it's a universal binary and there are not separate options for Initial interface orientation for iPad/iPhone, this is going to break the UI on iPhone (the app is portrait on iPhone). Even so, as a test, I tried it and it does not fix the problem. What could I do in viewDidLoad to remedy the problem?